# Creating a lisp file that reads numbers from the keyboard until 0 is read. Display the minimim value

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am stuck, I did it this way but I feel it is wrong.

```
(defun (find-min a b))
   (cond 
        (> a b) (find-min b (read))
        (< a b) (find-min a (read))
        )
   (display (find-min (read) (read)))
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing elements from Scheme (e.g. display) and Common Lisp (e.g. defun). Can you clarify which language you are trying to write, or the environnement you are using (Racket/guile/clisp) ? There is an "edit" button if you want to add details. Thank you !

Comment: I am doing it in clisp. I am a very beginner with this stuff.

Comment: No problem, this is just to clarify the scope of the question.

Comment: Create a Lisp file that reads numbers from the keyboard until 0 is read, and display the minimum of all read numbers. Note that 0 is included in the computation.
For example, if user enters:
  3
  6
-4
 12
 15
-9
-24
  4
-3
-5
  1
  0
then the procedure should return
-24
You will need to utilize “print” procedure to display the minimum value, and also utilize “read” procedure to keep reading the next number from the keyboard.

Comment: Any idea on how to start it out?

Comment: what is the expected result, if the first number read is `0` ? `0` or `nil` ? Does last `0` read gets included into the minimization process ? like 2 1 3 4 0 prints out 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

### Code review

The code as given is badly formatted. It is really important to test your code often, to check that at least the syntax is correct. Instead of writing the code in isolation, you should ask the environment, the interpreter, to parse your code and execute it. You'll have a shorter feedback loop, which will help getting the code right.

For example, if you start your interpreter (you mentionned `clisp`), you are in a Read Eval Print Loop (REPL), where you write Lisp forms, which are evaluated to produce a result, which is printed. So just by writing code, it will get parsed and evaluated, which can quickly inform you about possible errors.

So if you write the code as you wrote it, you will notice that the interpreter first reads this:

```
(defun (find-min a b))
```

This is because all parentheses are balanced: the *Lisp reader* (the R in REPL) will build a list of two elements, namely `defun` and the list `(find-min a b)`.
When evaluation is performed (the E in REPL), the list will be interpreted as a Lisp form, but this is a malformed `defun`.

[`DEFUN`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) expects a function name, followed by a list of variable bindings, followed by the function body. So you can try writing for example:

```
(defun find-min (a b)
  0)
```

This above defines a function named `find-min`, which accepts two parameters `a` and `b`, and always evaluate as 0 (the body of the function).

In your case you want to write:

```
(defun find-min (a b)
  (cond ...))
```

You [`COND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) form is malformed too:

```
   (cond 
        (> a b) (find-min b (read))
        (< a b) (find-min a (read))
        )
```

Each *clause* in a `cond` should be a **list** containing first a test, then zero or more expressions. So it would be:

```
(cond
  ((> a b) ...)
  ((< a b) ...))
```

Note that there is a remaining case, namely `(= a b)`, which is not addressed.

### Approach

But overall, I do not understand what your code is trying to achieve. Since all inputs are supposed to be obtained with `(read)`, there is no need to accept arguments `a` and `b`. The whole thing could be a loop:

```
(defun read-min ()
  (loop
    for val = (read)
    for zerop = (= val zero)
    for min = val then (if zerop min (min min val))
    until (= val 0)
    finally (return min)))
```

As suggested by @leetwinski, there is also a shorter alternative:

```
(loop for val = (read) until (= val 0) minimizing val)
```

But I suppose you are not expected to use the loop form, so you should try to write a recursive function that does the same.

What you need to do is to pass the current minimum value ever read to your function, recursively, like so:

```
(defun read-min-rec (min-so-far)
  ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. For the loop case, how would you display the result. because it is asking "You will need to utilize “print” procedure to display the minimum value, and also utilize “read” procedure to keep reading the next number from the keyboard."  how would you apply this.

Comment: the loop variant could be a bit shorter with `minimizing` : `(loop for val = (read) until (= val 0) minimizing val)`

Comment: I feel stupid asking this question, but what does "val" stand in this case

Comment: @leetwinski Yes, indeed, I forgot about it

Comment: @sarah `val` is the name of a loop variable, it just means "value" (I should have used that name instead, probably).